# Spectator Angular testing - pass input before ngOnInit

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-spectator

I am using [Spectator](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator#testing-components) to write my Angular 8 tests and [Jest](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator#testing-with-host) to run them. According to [the README](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator#testing-components) I can use `setInput()` to assign my value to the name of the field, which works. The problem is that The input is being validated AFTER the component is created, but I need it before that because I use it for initialization in my `ngOnInit` method:

```
// item.component.ts

@Input() items: Items[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    // do something with this.items
    // read query param 'page' and use it for something
}
```

with

```
// item.component.spec.ts

let spectator: SpectatorRouting<ItemComponent>;
const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: ItemComponent,
    queryParams: {page: 1}
});

beforeEach(() => spectator = createComponent());

it('test items', () => {
    spectator.setRouteQueryParam('page', '2');
    spectator.setInput("items", myItemsList); 
});
```

The spectator will set the queryParam `page` and Input `items` correctly, but only after the component is already created.  During the component creation `ngOnInit` will initialize with `page == 1` and `items == []`.

I could create the spectator component within each method and pass the queryParams separately, but I can't find a way to pass the input in the `createRoutingFactory` arguments.

Alternatively I could use [a host component factory](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator#testing-with-host) to pass my input parameters, but then I lose the ability to pass query params I believe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set detectChanges=false in the createRoutingFactory options. This will make  createComponent() not calling onInit() automatically, and in your tests you should call spectator.detectChanges() after setting the inputs (or stubing/mocking services spys):

```
// item.component.spec.ts

let spectator: SpectatorRouting<ItemComponent>;
const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: ItemComponent,
    queryParams: {page: 1},
    detectChanges: false // set this to avoid calling onInit() automatically
});

beforeEach(() => spectator = createComponent());

it('test items', () => {
    spectator.setRouteQueryParam('page', '2');
    // spectator.inject(AnyService).doSomething.andReturn()... // stub services if needed
    spectator.setInput("items", myItemsList); 
    spectator.detectChanges(); // Now onInit() will be called
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I learned this later on too.  I forgot about this question, otherwise I would have updated it.  I'll mark your solution as the answer since it's cleaner than calling `ngOnInit` again.  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to this question.  It turned out to be quite simple, `ngOnInit` can be called again to reinitialize the component after setting up the mocks and other parameters. So my test method becomes:

```
// item.component.spec.ts

let spectator: SpectatorRouting<ItemComponent>;
const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: ItemComponent,
    queryParams: {page: 1}
});

beforeEach(() => spectator = createComponent());

it('test items', () => {
    spectator.setRouteQueryParam('page', '2');
    spectator.setInput("items", myItemsList); 
    spectator.component.ngOnInit(); // Now the component is reinitialized and the input will contain myItemsList
});
```